# Can't commit database changes in Redgate. Git

Tags: database, git, redgate

I am experiencing a very strange behaviour of redgate that prevents me from commiting the changes I made to the database (I'm using git). I can click "Get Latest" and get no errors, everything works, but when I try to commit I get an error without any description (please see the screenshot).

I'm asking for help cause I have no idea what maybe wrong. Thanks in advance!

[image: s1]

Comment: Open the command prompt, enter `git checkout "Tables\dbo.Account.sql"` (i.e. the command without the `-q`) and report back the error it gives.

Comment: Executing the command with and without "-q" does not produce any output. No information about the error.

Comment: If `git checkout` does not produce any output, it succeeded, so your file was checked out correctly.

Comment: Yes, but I still can't commit using Redgate, it fails when checking out with error 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no idea what was causing the problem. I ended up committing the changes using Tortoise GIT.
Anyway, no one has spotted that Redgate is performing a git checkout trying to switch a branch into a file?! And surpressing the error with `-q`. This looks like a bug in redgate.

Maybe the developers misunderstood git's checkout and treated it as subversion's checkout, but this commands are completely different and they should have known it.

Thanks for all the answers.
Here is the post that put some light on my issue:
http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=15157

Answer (score 0):

One other suggestion is to create a copy of the GIT config file, (call it GIT2.xml) and add the -verbose switch to see if it then creates some useful output. You'll need to unlink and re-link with the new config file for it to be picked up.

Comment: adding -verbose does not produce any additional output

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your system's PATH is pointing to the right Git.exe. You may want to check your path for C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd and change that to C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin.